# Download podcast where the file name (date) changes weekly

Tags: regex, powershell, download, mp3

I want to be able to download a .MP3 podcast that comes out weekly, I've got a working script which downloads the file, the problem is the file name changes weekly (the date is in the file name)

news-2018-12-09.mp3,
news-2018-12-16.mp3,
news-2018-12-23.mp3.

This is the code I have:

```
# Start IE and navigate to your download file/location
$ie = New-Object -Com internetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate("<address>2018-12-09.mp3")

# Wait for Download Dialog box to pop up
Sleep 5
while ($ie.Busy) {Sleep 1}

# Hit "S" on the keyboard to hit the "Save" button on the download box
$obj = New-Object -Com WScript.Shell
$obj.AppActivate('Internet Explorer')
$obj.SendKeys('s')

# Hit "Enter" to save the file
$obj.SendKeys('{Enter}')

# Closes IE Downloads window
$obj.SendKeys('{TAB}')
$obj.SendKeys('{TAB}')
$obj.SendKeys('{TAB}')
$obj.SendKeys('{Enter}')
```

Is there a particular Regex sequence that would check and file name, download the current one, and possibly when saving the file, save it just as `news-current.mp3`?

Comment: Discard the code you currently have. Sending keystrokes is a last-resort type of automation. Use `Invoke-WebRequest` as described in the answer to the linked question. A URL with the current date in it can be crafted like this: `'https://example.org/{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.mp3' -f (Get-Date)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format of the file is always `news-` + current date + `.mp3` it can't be hard to construct that..
Something like `$fileName = 'news-{0}.mp3' -f (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd')` would do it.

As for the way to download the file, there are better ways of doing this I think than to make use of the Internet Explorer Com object.

```
$address     = '<PUT THE URL FOR THE DOWNLOAD IN HERE>'
$fileName    = 'news-{0}.mp3' -f (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd')
$downloadUrl = '{0}/{1}' -f $address, $fileName
$outputFile  = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath 'news-current.mp3'
```

1. [.NET WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

   ```
   (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($downloadUrl, $outputFile)
   ```
2. [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6).

   ```
   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $downloadUrl -OutFile $outputFile
   ```
3. [Start-BitsTransfer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitstransfer/start-bitstransfer?view=win10-ps).

   ```
   Import-Module BitsTransfer  
   Start-BitsTransfer -Source $downloadUrl -Destination $outputFile
   ```

Comment: @Ansgar-Wiechers Thanks for the edit.